# C# Reflection Indexed Properties

Tags: c#, reflection, clone

I am writing a Clone method using reflection. How do I detect that a property is an indexed property using reflection?  For example:

```
public string[] Items
{
   get;
   set;
}
```

My method so far:

```
public static T Clone<T>(T from, List<string> propertiesToIgnore) where T : new()
{
    T to = new T();

    Type myType = from.GetType();

    PropertyInfo[] myProperties = myType.GetProperties();

    for (int i = 0; i < myProperties.Length; i++)
    {
        if (myProperties[i].CanWrite && !propertiesToIgnore.Contains(myProperties[i].Name))
        {
            myProperties[i].SetValue(to,myProperties[i].GetValue(from,null),null);
        }
    }

    return to;
}
```

Comment: That is not an indexed property, that is a property that returns an array.

Comment: This question needs to be changed by a moderator.  It is the top google result for finding an indexer property but that isn't what the code example illustrates.  Half the answers below answer the question and half the code example.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
if (propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0)
{
    // Property is an indexer
}
```

Answer (score 9):

What you want is the `GetIndexParameters()` method. If the array that it returns has more than 0 items, that means it's an indexed property.

See [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getindexparameters.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

If you call `property.GetValue(obj,null)`, and the property IS indexed, then you will get a parameter count mismatch exception.  Better to check whether the property is indexed using `GetIndexParameters()` and then decide what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that worked for me:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
{
  object value = property.GetValue(obj, null);
  if (value is object[])
  {
    ....
  }
}
```

P.S.  `.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0)` works for the case described in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx
So if you care about the property named Chars for a value of type string, use that, but it does not work for most of the arrays I was interested in, including, I am pretty sure, a string array from the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the indexer to IEnumerable

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this object o) where T : class {
        var list = new List<T>();
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo indexerProperty = null;
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi in o.GetType().GetProperties()) {
            if (pi.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0) {
                indexerProperty = pi;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (indexerProperty.IsNotNull()) {
            var len = o.GetPropertyValue<int>("Length");
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var item = indexerProperty.GetValue(o, new object[]{i});
                if (item.IsNotNull()) {
                    var itemObject = item as T;
                    if (itemObject.IsNotNull()) {
                        list.Add(itemObject);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return list;
    }


    public static bool IsNotNull(this object o) {
        return o != null;
    }

    public static T GetPropertyValue<T>(this object source, string property) {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        var sourceType = source.GetType();
        var sourceProperties = sourceType.GetProperties();
        var properties = sourceProperties
            .Where(s => s.Name.Equals(property));
        if (properties.Count() == 0) {
            sourceProperties = sourceType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            properties = sourceProperties.Where(s => s.Name.Equals(property));
        }

        if (properties.Count() > 0) {
            var propertyValue = properties
                .Select(s => s.GetValue(source, null))
                .FirstOrDefault();

            return propertyValue != null ? (T)propertyValue : default(T);
        }

        return default(T);
    }
```

Comment: I'm thinking this only handles single-integer-indexer properties, right? no string-based indexers, no multiple index parameters... or am I missing something?

Comment: @CodeJockey — You may be correct; I'm having trouble getting it to work with a `String` input type. It's hanging up on the `Chars` indexed property. Unless I'm missing something myself...