# Reflections -Set objects property when the property is in a List<>

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I know I can use reflection to set a objects property like this below.

```
    public void SaveContent(string propertyName, string contentToUpdate, string corePageId)
    {
        var page = Session.Load<CorePage>(corePageId);
        Type type = page.GetType();
        PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
        prop.SetValue(page, contentToUpdate, null);
    }
```

I'm having these classes below:

```
public class CorePage
{
    public string BigHeader { get; set; }
    public List<BigLinks> BigLinks { get; set; }
}

 public class BigLinks
{
    public string TextContent { get; set; }
}
```

My `SaveContent()`-method works obviously when the property to set is, for example `public string BigHeader { get; set; }`
But how can I do this if the the property I want to set is in the property:

```
public List<BigLinks> BigLinks { get; set; }
```

If `public List<BigLinks> BigLinks { get; set; }` is a list of 5 `BigLinks` objects, how can a set the value of, for example the third objects `public string TextContent { get; set; }`?

Comment: Are you trying to serialize the content?

Comment: This link might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291359/c-sharp-reflection-indexed-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the property value using reflection and change the desired value like this:

```
var c = new CorePage() { BigLinks = new List<BigLinks> { new BigLinks { TextContent = "Y"}}};
var r = typeof(CorePage).GetProperty("BigLinks").GetGetMethod().Invoke(c, null) as List<BigLinks>;
    r[0].TextContent = "X";
```

If you don't know the type of list item:

```
var itemInList = (typeof(CorePage).GetProperty("BigLinks").GetGetMethod().Invoke(c, null) as IList)[0];
itemInList.GetType().GetProperty("TextContent").SetValue(itemInList, "XXX", null);
```

Another option is casting to dynamic:

```
var itemInList = (typeof(CorePage).GetProperty("BigLinks").GetGetMethod().Invoke(c, null) as dynamic)[0].TextContent = "XXXTTT";
```

Comment: Can I do this without the cast: `as List<BigLinks>;`? I need to have it in a more dynamic way, because the `List<>` is not always `List<BigLinks>` And I don't want to have a method for each of my possible List<>

Comment: How do you want to use it ? It's common to have all classes that are used in place of BigLinks implement a common interface like IBigLink and have a List<IBigLink> in your CorePage instead of List<BigLink>.

Comment: casting back to the type defeats the purpose of using reflection. if he knew what type to cast it to, he wouldn't be using reflection.

Comment: @brz What I mean is that the List to cast could be any other List<>. CorePage-class also have other Lists, like: `public List<AnotherList> AnotherList { get; set; }` Then I have to cast it like that, witch means I need a cast for any possible list. Was just thinking of it could be done in amore dynamic way